# How to display values using Multiple Join in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key

I have to show the names of each pair of friends, based on the data in the friends table using JOIN. [image: My output should come exactly like this]
i have attached the my expected result image below

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
fullname TEXT,
age INTEGER);

INSERT INTO persons (fullname, age) VALUES ("Bobby McBobbyFace", "12");
INSERT INTO persons (fullname, age) VALUES ("Lucy BoBucie", "25");
INSERT INTO persons (fullname, age) VALUES ("Banana FoFanna", "14");
INSERT INTO persons (fullname, age) VALUES ("Shish Kabob", "20");
INSERT INTO persons (fullname, age) VALUES ("Fluffy Sparkles", "8");

CREATE table hobbies (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
person_id INTEGER,
name TEXT);

INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (1, "drawing");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (1, "coding");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (2, "dancing");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (2, "coding");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (3, "skating");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (3, "rowing");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (3, "drawing");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (4, "coding");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (4, "dilly-dallying");
INSERT INTO hobbies (person_id, name) VALUES (4, "meowing");

CREATE table friends (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
person1_id INTEGER,
person2_id INTEGER);

INSERT INTO friends (person1_id, person2_id)
VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO friends (person1_id, person2_id)
VALUES (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically needs an `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.fullname,s.fullname
FROM persons t
INNER JOIN friends f
 ON(t.id = f.person1_id)
INNER JOIN persons s
 ON(f.person2_id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Query

```
SELECT p1.fullname, p2.fullname 
FROM friends f 
JOIN persons p1 on f.person1_id = p1.id 
JOIN persons p2 on f.person2_id = p2.id
```